# Algorithm for unique clustering of points belonging to different classes

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have points (which are feature vectors of images) belonging to different classes(there are classes in my database that have those points distributed among them) and number of clusters to be formed are unknown.
What I am looking for is a clustering algorithm that would cluster those points in such a way that clusters formed have **unique** points from each class. By unique, I mean that no two points in a cluster should belong to the same class. That is, if i have 5 classes, then each cluster should have only 5 points; each from different class.

After this I would like to search for the most dense cluster among the clusters formed to get similar points(images) from different classes.

I have been through many clustering algorithms, but most of them are generic and are not useful to me. I would really appreciate if someone can help me in solving this or by providing any useful links that could sort this out.

Comment: This does not sound like clustering to me, but rather a *set cover* type of algorithm.

Comment: This seems like the opposite to clustering

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very interesting a peculiar algorithm. I think you are right, standard methods do not consider this type characteristics/restrictions you are mentioning. In my opinion you should create a new clustering method, specifically for your application. However, it is not necessary to create everything form scratch, because you can modify existing methods to incorporate your restrictions. For example, a modification of k-means that picks elements of different classes at each step. This is and example of algorithm design. If you are graduate student, read about clustering. if your domain knowledge goes beyond computer science/machine learning, think about associating with a machine learning expert.